# Flutter web HTTP exception Error: XMLHttpRequest error

Tags: flutter, web

While calling an API (not mine, a 3rd party server), using the [HTTP package](https://pub.dev/packages/http/install), I get the following error:

Error: XMLHttpRequest error.

dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 906:28                get current

I get this **only when running locally on web**, not with the iOS emulator (works just fine there).

[This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63763) didn't help me

Here's the code:

```
try {
  response = await _httpClient.get(
    Uri(
      scheme: 'http',
      host: host,
      path: path,
    ),
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: That header needs to be added by the *server* to its response. Adding that header to the *request* will do nothing. Does the 3rd party server expect to be called from a browser? Do they provide a way to set CORS headers? (Also, the server normally needs to set *other* headers too, as well as reply to OPTIONS requests.)

Answer (score 0):

well, changed scheme: 'http' to scheme: 'https' and it works...
Don't know why it works on mobile and not on web